# Laravel eloquent query using local scope with conditional statement and arguments

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I've written the following function in my Car model that does the following:

1. Gets the related reservations based on two dates(pickup/dropoff)
2. Checks if the amount of these reservations are equal or exceed the quantity of the car
3. Finally returns a boolean depending on the output

```
   /**
    * Custom Functions
    */

   public function isAvailableFor($from, $to) {
       $reservationsCount = $this->reservations->where('pickup_date', '>=', $from)->where('dropoff_date', '<=', $to)->count();
       if($reservationsCount >= $this->quantity) {
           return false;
       }
       return true;
   }
```

The function is working as expected but I want to implement this in a more elegant way using local scopes so I can actually use it efficiently when querying the Car model in my controllers but I can't find the correct way to do it and my code becomes a complete mess.

For example I have the following scope that I am using by just typing `Car::active()->get();`

```
    /**
     * Scopes
     */
    public function scopeActive($query)
    {
        return $query->where('status', 'active');
    }
```

The main problem is the `count()` function that doesn't let me implement my function in a scope-way or at least I am not that experienced to come up with a solution.
Thanks in advance.

**Update**

As correctly pointed by OsDev since my function returns a boolean it can not be implemented directly in the scope function. I can alternatively do this in my scope function but I guess it is pretty much an overkill:

```
    public function scopeAvailable($query, $from, $to) {
        $excludedId = array();
        $cars = Car::whereHas('reservations')->get();
        foreach($cars as $car) {
            if(!$car->isAvailableFor($from, $to)) {
                array_push($excludedId, $car->id);
            }
        }
        return $query->whereNotIn('id', $excludedId);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to return the `$query` instead the count result because that way you don't break the Query Builder chain

You can't combine scopes and Model functions because scopes are supposed to return the `$query` builder object and in that example, your function is returning a boolean.

#### You can do something like this

```
  /**
     * Scopes
     */
    public function scopeIsAvailableFor($query,$from,$to)
    {
        return $query->where('pickup_date', '>=', $from)->where('dropoff_date', '<=', $to);
    }
```

#### Then you can chain it and call count if you want

```
$count = Car::active()->isAvailableFor('2020-05-03','2020-05-06')->count();
```

#### Maybe you can wrap your new scope into your model method

```
public function isAvailableFor($from, $to) {

    $reservationsCount = $this->reservations->isAvailableFor($from,$to)->count();

    return !$reservationsCount >= $this->quantity;

   }
```

Comment: Unfortunately you can't do this, since `$this->reservations` will result in null because there is not any data at that point in the scope. Alternatively i can do this in scope but i guess it is pretty much an overkill
`public function scopeAvailable($query, $from, $to) { $excludedId = array(); $cars = Car::whereHas('reservations')->get(); foreach($cars as $car) { if(!$car->isAvailableFor($from, $to)) { array_push($excludedId, $car->id); } } return $query->whereNotIn('id', $excludedId);}`

Comment: Sorry for the long message, here is an implode.io [link](https://implode.io/nLWfb1)